# Xperia Play Sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, playback, sony

Does anyone know what are the available sensors on the xperia play? I have checked the available sensors using the sensor manager in an app, it lists 8 sensors and in the list there is no light sensor yet there is one above the screen like a little rectangle. So is there any details as to what the sensors are?

Comment: that little thing might be a proximity sensor that has usually only a very few states: something is close, (maybe something in between), nothing close. Or that sensor is simply not available via SensorManager

Comment: Sensormanager should list all the available sensors for your phone, a lot of the sensors on phones are multifunctional so it's possible the proximity sensor is functioning as a light sensor also, this is certainly true on my HTC desire. Still as your get a list of all devices from sensorManager it is either there or it isn't.

Comment: ah ok thats fine so, just means im going to have to be a bit more clever with the programming ha thanks very much guys thats a big help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Xperia Play and i've tried an app called "Android Sensor Box"

i don't have the following: 
light sensor
gyroscope
temperature
and pressure sensors

I hope it helps :)

Comment: haha thanks but that project is over for the time being, gonna work on something complex using the sensors at some stage though.

Comment: you are welcome, just trying to help, maybe u'll need it latter, who knows!... There's one source that says that some versions of Xperia play has gyro, it says "SonyEricsson Xperia play R800i - not in AndroidFragm" but i don't know what does that mean... check this link: http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/308045-androids-gyros-2.html

Comment: awesome! its nice of you mate. annoyingly my account on this is not longer allowing me to ask questions cause my questions were too abstract or something ~_~ grr ha but still good to know that i can receive help on this :) cheers